# change operator output type and value in hsqldb

Tags: database, open-source, hsqldb

I have hsqldb source with me i want to modify date operations in source code, in such way  date1 - date2 operation should give output type as "INTEGER" instead of "INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND" type and also it should give date difference.

Please let me know how and where i need to modify in hsqldb source.

Note: I do not want to use datediff method.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are only interested in the number of days between the two dates.

```
extract( day from( date1 - date2 ));
```

I have hsqldb installed but it's not running at the moment so I can't test this but it should be really close to what you want.